# How to compare single hashmap values

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to use the HashMap to check the weather in a certain period For example one week.
I need to check if the weather becoming colder, warmer, same, or unsteady.

```
    Map<LocalDate , Integer > weatherMap = new HashMap<>();
    weatherMap.put(LocalDate.of(2020,12,12), 12);
    weatherMap.put(LocalDate.of(2020,12,13), 11);
    weatherMap.put(LocalDate.of(2020,12,14), 10);
```

can anyone help me with iterating inside the values and check them

Answer (score 1):

Use `TreeMap`, it keeps keys sorted (in increasing order, by default).
To iterate through entries, you can use one of these approaches:

Lambda for-each:

```
weatherMap.forEach((date, temp) -> {
    // your code
});
```

Traditional for-each:

```
for (Map.Entry<LocalDate, Integer> entry : weatherMap.entrySet()) {
     // your code
}
```

If you want to keep track of value changes between iterations, the latter is more convenient:

```
int prevTemp = -100;
for (Map.Entry<LocalDate, Integer> entry : weatherMap.entrySet()) {
     int curTemp = entry.getvalue();
     if (prevTemp != -100) { // there was a previous temp
         // your code - compare with curTemp
     }
     
     prevTemp = curTemp;
}
```

Comment: I have one issue how to compare the temp.getVaue() with the next value in foreach

Comment: @AliIhlail in the lambda version, temp is the value in the map, the temperature.
In the for-each version, entry.getValue() is the temperature, It's simpler to compare current value with previous, I'll add in the example

Answer (score 0):

You can increment the date and check your HashMap for a temperature on a particular date:

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2020,12,12);
int numberOfDays=7;
int temp = 12;
for(int i=0;i<numberOfDays;i++){
  int newTemp = weatherMap.getOrDefault(startDate, temp);
  /* your code to compare temperatures*/
  temp=newTemp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use iterator ...
The classic approach would look like this :

```
Set s = map.entrySet();
Iterator i = s.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(i.next());
}
```

A shortest way using iterator would be this one. I didn't test the code i can't tell about the logic in it but it should look like this. Maybe you'll have to use AtomicInteger instead of int:

```
int temp = 0;
int loop = 0;
weatherMap.entrySet()
    .forEach((entry) -> {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue())
        if(loop == 0) {
           temp = entry.getValue()
        }
        if(loop != 0 && temp > entry.getValue()) {
           // it's hotter
           temp = entry.getValue()
        } else if(temp < entry.getValue()) {
          // colder
          temp = entry.getValue()
        } else {
          // Same temp
        }
        loop++;            
     }
);
```

Comment: Just iterating over a HashMap might not work as there is no guarantee what order the iterator will give you. A TreeMap will let you constrain the order.

Comment: As a matter of style, this is not a recommended use of the `forEach` Stream operation. If you want to iterate over a collection, just use a `for` statement. As your code stands, it won't even compile.  A lambda is not able to capture variables that are not final or effectively final.

Comment: I think this code give always equal results.